# How to add X-Content-Type-Options to tomcat configuration

Tags: java, security, tomcat, mime-types, httpresponse

My client want me to fix Web App vulnerability of My Web App
 below is message about vulnerability of My Web App

> The Anti-MIME-Sniffing header X-Content-Type-Options was not set to 'nosniff'
>
> This check is specific to Internet Explorer 8 and Google Chrome. Ensure each page sets a >Content-Type header and the X-CONTENT-TYPE-OPTIONS if the Content-Type header is unknown

Although I already found some solution to this issue , I am looking for solution from tomcat configuration.
Is it possible to make changes to tomcat configuration to accomplish this?

please give me any idea.

Comment: Not sure you can configure Tomcat to do this, but you could use a `Filter` to put this header on all responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can achieve it on Tomcat level by the following steps:

- create your filter, package it into jar, put jar into `$CATALINA_BASE/lib/`
- add filter definition into `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`

Comment: can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Sure, what you do is create a custom implementation of `javax.servlet.Filter`(let's name it `org.happenask.filter.ContentTypeOptionsFilter`), package it into jar with maven or whatever, drop it into `$CATALINA_BASE/lib/` and after that define it in `web.xml` as filter with name/mapping that you want and set filter class to `<filter-class>org.happenask.filter.ContentTypeOptionsFilter</filter-class>`

Answer (score 18):

If you're using Tomcat 8, it's really easy - add these two sections to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>HeaderSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HeaderSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The server response now has 'nosniff' and X-Frame-Options: DENY by default

[image: Server response]

More detail: [Tomcat 8 Filter Configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#HTTP_Header_Security_Filter)

Answer (score 9):

Sample filter class code.

```
public class SampleResponseFilter implements Filter  {

  @Override
  public void destroy() { }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    // Protection against Type 1 Reflected XSS attacks
    res.addHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block");
    // Disabling browsers to perform risky mime sniffing
    res.addHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    chain.doFilter(req,res);
  }

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To supplement on the answer by Ed Noriss. If I just use a filter mappen like this

```
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HeaderSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

to target everything, there will be some unnecessary headers (x-xss-protection and X-Frame-Options) when loading media-resources such as jpg, png etc. (according to https://sonarwhal.com linting tool).

In order to avoid theses I've created two filters and mappings like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurityNoX</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
        <param-name>antiClickJackingEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xssProtectionEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
```

...

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurityNoX</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurityNoX</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

and several more filter mappings hitting httpHeaderSecurityNoX for each of these extensions: png, gif, js, css, ico (maybe it could be contained in one single url-pattern?)

The init-param

```
xssProtectionEnabled
```

was not listed in the Tomcat web.xml comments, but found it here

https://vk4u.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/how-to-enable-security-filters-in-tomcat/